# Changing code to not use namespaces from boost

Tags: boost, namespaces

```
namespace boost { namespace serialization {
template<class Archive>
void save(Archive & ar, const my_class & t, unsigned int version)
{
....
}
template<class Archive>
void load(Archive & ar, my_class & t, unsigned int version)
{
....
}
}}
```

I need to use this code within a class but I'm getting errors due to the namespaces. Any help? From the docs: https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/libs/serialization/doc/serialization.html#splittingfreefunctions

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer was to just place the entirety of the namespace outside of the class.

Answer (score 1):

You are confusing intrusive serialization (member function) with unintrusive  (free functions).

The coffee you post is for free functions (which can be used eg when you cannot add serialization code to a class (it might be from a third party header).

Inside a class definition you should take the member functions approach: https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_72_0/libs/serialization/doc/serialization.html#member

If you also need to split save/load functions you can do that as member functions too: https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_72_0/libs/serialization/doc/serialization.html#splittingmemberfunctions